# JavaScript: 0 represents true in some cases?

Tags: javascript

I was checking the JS spec, and ran into this strange behaviour:

- Say you have an array of animals.
- Say you want one number to represent the animals you have, to save memory.

  - That number actually represents the binary value of the number, wich can be used to convert to an array of booleans.
- converting that number to its binary value, you have to split it into an array and `pop` the value every time, because you don't have leading `0`'s.

Okay that sounds vague, so lets put an example in position:

```js
var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'salamander', 'fish', 'lion', 'ape'];

var iHavePets = parseInt(1001, 2); // 9
// we can't have leading 0's, so read this right to left.
// this actually represents 001001

var petBools = iHavePets.toString(2).split("");
console.log(petBools);

while(pets.length > 0){
   // petBools == [1, 0, 0, 1]
   // popping it would represent: 1, 0, 0, 1, undefined, undefined
    console.log(petBools.pop() ? !!pets.pop() : !pets.pop());
}
// remember we pop(), so read right to left in the array's.
// here I expect the following:
// We start with a 1
// so pets.pop() should push true
// then we have a 0
// so !pets.pop() should push false.
// however: the 0 is actually true in this case, causing it to push 'true'.
```

The same example by hand DOES work:

```js
var fish = ['salmon', 'tuna', 'shark'];
console.log(1 ? !!fish.pop() : !fish.pop()); // true
console.log(0 ? !!fish.pop() : !fish.pop()); // false
console.log(undefined ? !!fish.pop() : !fish.pop()); // false
```

Could someone explain to me why JS is behaving this weird?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> JavaScript: 0 represents true in some cases?

No, the value `0` is never truthy. The value `"0"` is truthy (a *string* containing the digit `0`), but the value `0` is not. The fact that `"0"` (the **string**) is truthy is why your first example behaves the way it does.

If you want your loop to show the results you expect, coerce the string to number:

```
console.log(+petBools.pop() ? !!pets.pop() : !pets.pop());
// ---------^
```

or convert rather than coerce (just changes the rules slightly, no difference for `"0"` or `"1"`):

```
console.log(parseInt(petBools.pop()) ? !!pets.pop() : !pets.pop());
// ---------^^^^^^^^
```

> why JS is behaving this weird?

Because `pop` is a *mutating operation*. If you use the same array for all the operations, you'll get consistent results:

```js
var fish;
fish = ['salmon', 'tuna', 'shark'];
console.log(1 ? !!fish.pop() : !fish.pop());
fish = ['salmon', 'tuna', 'shark'];
console.log(0 ? !!fish.pop() : !fish.pop());
fish = ['salmon', 'tuna', 'shark'];
console.log(undefined ? !!fish.pop() : !fish.pop());
```

Comment: Great to know that the `+` operator does that trick. I think for production though, I'd use `parseInt` for verbosity.

Comment: @randy: Just note that they do different things. `+""` is `0`, for instance, whereas `parseInt("")` is `NaN`, and of course `parseInt` lets you specify a radix but also only gives you whole numbers. `parseInt` also ignores trailing non-numeric characters; `parseInt("123abc")` is `123` whereas `+"123abc"` is `NaN`. There's also `parseFloat`. No radix, lets you do floating point, but also has that "ignore trailing non-numerics" issue.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `'0'` in your case is **string** 0 and not the number 0

If you change the `0` to number 0 you will have the expected behaviour of `false`

```js
    var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'salamander', 'fish', 'lion', 'ape'];

    var iHavePets = parseInt(1001, 2);
    // we can't have leading 0's, so read this right to left.
    // this actually represents 001001

    var petBools = iHavePets.toString(2).split("");
    console.log(petBools);

    while(pets.length > 0){
      // petBools == [1, 0, 0, 1]
      //console.log(petBools);
      var poppedValue = parseInt(petBools.pop(), 10)
      // popping it would represent: 1, 0, 0, 1, undefined, undefined
      console.log(poppedValue ? !!pets.pop() : !pets.pop());
    }
    // remember we pop(), so read right to left in the array's.
    // here I expect the following:
    // We start with a 1
    // so pets.pop() should push true
    // then we have a 0
    // so !pets.pop() should push false.
    // however: the 0 is actually true in this case, causing it to push 'true'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains string of "0" and "1" .And string "0" or "1" is truthy